Inverse Mellin transform of $\Delta(t):=\sum_{s=1}^\infty d(s)\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}M_1(4\pi \sqrt{ts})$
Define
$$ \Delta(t):=\sum_{s=1}^\infty d(s)\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}M_1(4\pi \sqrt{ts}) $$
where $M_1(z)=-Y_1{(z)}-\frac{2}{\pi}K_1(z)$ and $d(s)$ is the divisor function.

What is the inverse Mellin transform of $\Delta$?

$\Delta(t)$ is conjectured to grow on the order of magnitude of $O(t^{1/4+\epsilon})$ as $t\to \infty$.
I expanded and distributed the sum to obtain
$$ \Delta(t)= -\sum_{s=1}^\infty d(s) \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}Y_1{(4\pi\sqrt{ts})}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{s=1}^\infty d(s)\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(4\pi \sqrt{ts}) $$
I found that
$$\Delta(t)=-\Pi(t)-\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{(0,1)}\sum_{s=1}^\infty d(s)~e^{\frac{16\pi^2 t}{\log x}}~x^{s-1} ~dx  $$
where the integrand is the inverse Mellin transform of the $K_1$ terms and where $\Pi(t)$ is the remainder of the $Y_1$ terms. I'm not sure how to express $\Pi(t)$ as a Mellin transform of another function.
Here are the definitions I am using
$$ Y_n(z):=\lim_{v \to n} Y_v(z) $$
for $n\in \Bbb Z.$
and
$$ K_n(z)=\lim_{v \to n} K_v(z) $$
for $n\in \Bbb Z$.
Where
$$ Y_v(z)= \frac{J_v(z)(v\pi)-J_{-v}(z)}{\sin(v\pi)} $$
for $z\in \Bbb C$ and $v \notin \Bbb Z$.
and finally
$$   K_v(z)= \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{I_{-v}(z)-I_{v}(z)}{\sin(v\pi)}   $$
for $z\in \Bbb C$ and $v\notin \Bbb Z$.

What are your definitions of $K_1$ and $Y_1$, Do these correspond to Bessel functions?

Yes @StevenClark but let me add the explicit definitions im using

@StevenClark I've included the definitions, thanks

This question is ill-posed; the function $\Delta(t)$ is a function of the variable $t \in (0,\infty)$, not of a complex variable $t$ lying in a vertical strip. So one cannot take the inverse Mellin transform. Note that unlike the Fourier transform, the Mellin transform and inverse Mellin transforms lead to functions of a very differently behaved variable, so one cannot freely take such transforms if the domain of the function does not match up to that of the correct transform.

Gotcha thanks Peter

For the divisor summatory function
$$D(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x d(n)\tag{1}$$
one has $$\zeta(s)^2=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[D(x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty D(x)\, x^{-s-1}\, dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)}{n^s},\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{2}$$
where the integral is evaluated term-wise.

Wikipedia indicates $\Delta(x)$ is given by the inverse Mellin transform
$$\Delta(x)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\zeta(s)^2}{s}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{c'-i \infty}^{c'+i \infty} \zeta(s)^2\, \frac{x^s}{s} \, ds,\quad 0<c'<1\tag{3}$$
where
$$D(x)=x \log(x)+(2 \gamma-1)\, x+\Delta(x)\tag{4}.$$

Defining $\Delta(x)$ slightly differently as
$$\Delta(x)=\Delta_k(x)+\Delta_Y(x)\tag{5}$$
where
$$D(x)=x \log(x)+(2 \gamma-1)\, x+\frac{1}{4}+\Delta(x)\tag{6},$$
$$\Delta_K(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi} \sqrt{x} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)}{\sqrt{n}} K_1\left(4 \pi \sqrt{n x}\right)\tag{7},$$
and
$$\Delta_Y(x)=-\sqrt{x} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)}{\sqrt{n}} Y_1\left(4 \pi \sqrt{n x}\right)\tag{8}$$
evaluating term-wise Mathematica gives the Mellin Transform
$$s\, \mathcal{M}_x\left[\Delta_K(x)\right](-s)=s \int\limits_0^{\infty} \Delta_K(x)\, x^{-s-1} \, dx\\=2^{2 s-1}\, \pi^{2 s-2}\, \Gamma(1-s)^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} d(n)\, n^{s-1}=\frac{1}{2}\, \csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)^2\, \zeta(s)^2,\quad\Re(s)<0\tag{9}$$
where the condition is inconsistent with the condition in formula (3) above.

This would seem to imply
$$s\, \mathcal{M}_x\left[\Delta_Y(x)\right](-s)=s \int\limits_0^{\infty} \Delta_Y(x)\, x^{-s-1} \, dx\\=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\, \csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)^2\right)\, \zeta(s)^2\tag{10}$$
in some sense.

Evaluating term-wise Mathematica indicates the inverse Mellin transform of $\Delta_K(x)$ is
$$\mathcal{M}_x^{-1}\left[\Delta_K(x)\right](y)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \Delta_K(x)\, x^{-y} \, dx=\\-\frac{2}{\log^2(y)} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} d(n)\, e^{\frac{4 n \pi^2}{\log(y)}}=-\frac{2 \left(\psi_{e^{\frac{4 \pi^2}{\log(y)}}}^{(0)}(1)+\log\left(1-e^{\frac{4 \pi^2}{\log(y)}}\right)\right)}{\log\left(e^{\frac{4 \pi^2}{\log(y)}}\right) \log^2(y)},\quad 0<y<1\tag{11}$$
where $\psi _q^{(n)}(z)$ is the q-polygamma function.

The following figures illustrate the magnitude of $\Delta_K(x)$ decreases rapidly when evaluated along vertical lines, whereas the magnitude of $\Delta_Y(x)$ increases rapidly when evaluated along vertical lines which makes me suspect the inverse Mellin transform of $\Delta_Y(x)$ doesn't converge.


Figure (1): Illustration of $\left|\Delta_K(2+i t)\right|$ where formula (7) is evaluated at $N=100$


Figure (2): Illustration of $\left|\Delta_Y(2+i t)\right|$ where formula (8) is evaluated at $N=100$

Expressing $\Delta$ as the Mellin transform of some function would be valuable in the sense that one could port the asymptotic relation to a different function space where it might be easier to deal with

Steven I appreciate your attempt. But I am considering downvoting this because I feel it does not address the question. If I wanted the Mellin transform of something to obtain the Riemann zeta function I would have asked that instead. I hope you can see the difference.

@JohnZimmerman I thought perhaps you were confusing the inverse Mellin transform with the Mellin transform in which case your question makes sense, but if you really mean the inverse Mellin transform then I believe your question is misguided because I believe the magnitude of $\Delta(a+i y)$ grows rapidly as $y$ increases and therefore the inverse Mellin transform integral doesn't converge.

Steven, for the $K_1$ term it does converge. For the $Y_1$ it may not. Could you update your answer?

@JohnZimmerman I didn't look separately at the two terms yet as I just plotted $\Delta(a+i y)$ for several values of $a$, but I'll look at it some more and update my answer. With respect to my answer above, I was able to derive the Mellin transform related to the $K_1$ function which implies the result for the Mellin transform related to the $Y_1$ function.
