these pde's and the Dirichlet divsor problem
I noticed that
$$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}\Delta_t(s)+s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Delta_t(s)=0 $$
is satisfied by
$$\Delta_t(s)= - \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}Y_1{(4\pi\sqrt{ts})}+ \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(4\pi \sqrt{ts})$$
for $Y_1$ and $K_1$ Bessel functions.
I  noticed this looked similar to the "error term" in the Dirichlet divisor problem
$$\Delta(t)= -\sum_{s \in \Bbb N} d(s) \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}Y_1{(4\pi\sqrt{ts})}-\sum_{s \in \Bbb N} d(s)\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(4\pi \sqrt{ts})$$
I know from number theory that the order of magnitude of $\Delta(t)$ as $t\to \infty$ is close to $O(t^{1/4+\epsilon}).$ Making this exact is the notorious Dirichlet divsor problem.
I wonder if there are techniques from the theory of pde's that I can use to show this asymptotic holds or at least get close.
I observed that
$$t^2\frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Psi_n(t,s)=s^2\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Psi_n(t,s)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty b(n)\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi_n(t,s)$$
has a solution
$$\Psi_n(t,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{tn}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{t ns})$$
where the coefficients are
$$b(n)=\big\lbrace 2,12,24,40,60,84, \cdot\cdot\cdot\big\rbrace.$$
which I noticed correspond to twice the pronic/oblong numbers (if you throw out the first term $2$).
I thought about writing out the coefficients of the sequence $r(n)$ (to be determined) for the PDE corresponding to $Y_1$ as we did for $b(n)$ corresponding to $K_1$.
Then through linearity of solutions we can obtain a PDE involving both $r(n)$ and $b(n)$:
$$t^2\frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_n(t,s)+s^2\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_n(t,s)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty r(n)\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \chi_n(t,s)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty b(n)\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \chi_n(t,s)$$
where $$\chi_n(t,s)=-2 \sqrt{\frac{tn}{s}}Y_1{(2\sqrt{tns})}+2 \sqrt{\frac{tn}{s}}K_1(2 \sqrt{tns})$$

Is $r(n)$ a known arithmetic sequence?


I'm confused. Is the index $s$ in $\Delta(t)$ related to the variable $s$ in the PDE?

@Gonçalo oh yes - I just clarified the matter, let me know if you understand.

@Gonçalo essentially I am summing over the $s$ variable in the solution to the original diff eq.

How is $d(s)$ defined for non integer $s$?

I don't see how you can differentiate w.r.t. $s$ while also summing over $s$ as if it is a discrete index

I can't seem to verify your PDE is satisfied by your definition of $\Delta_t(s)$, Is there a typo somewhere?

@StevenClark did you try verifying using a CAS? I verified $- \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}Y_1{(4\pi\sqrt{ts})}$ and then I verified $- \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(4\pi \sqrt{ts})$ separtely. Then I combined them and used linearity of solutions to verify the DE for $\Delta_t(s)$

@StevenClark for example $f_t(s)=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{ts})$ satisfies $t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}f_t(s)=s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f_t(s).$

Yes, but I believe you have a sign problem since $g_t(s)=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}Y_1(2\sqrt{ts})$ satisfies $t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}g_t(s)=-s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} g_t(s).$

@StevenClark This can be resolved by taking $-g_t(s)$ and taking $f_t(s)$

@StevenClark and I changed the question to a simpler one

Since $$f_t(s)=\pm 2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{ts})$$ and $$g_t(s)=\pm 2\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}Y_1(2\sqrt{ts})$$ satisfy $$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}f_t(s)=s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f_t(s)$$ and $$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}g_t(s)=-s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} g_t(s)$$ respectively, you can't really combine them that way, but could you please give a reference for your formula for the "error term" in the Dirichlet divisor problem?

Your formula  for the "error term" in the Dirichlet divisor problem doesn't seem to match formula 1.1 here for example. Your formula seems to be missing the $\frac{2}{\pi}$ scaling on the $K_1$ function.

@StevenClark I threw out that constant to make things easier with the pde

I believe our relationship is wrong and the correct relationship is $$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \Psi_n(t,s)\right)=s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n, \Psi _(t,s)\right)$$ which follows from $$t^2 \frac{\partial^3, \Psi_n(t,s)}{\partial t^3}=n, s^2 \frac{\partial, \Psi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}$$ where $$\Psi_n(t,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{n t}{s}} K_1\left(2 \sqrt{t n s}\right).$$

please correct that formula - it's unclear what you mean

If you want to split the sum on the right-hand side instead of the way I wrote it in my previous comment, I believe your formula should actually be $$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \Psi_n(t,s)=s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Psi_n(t,s)+s^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty b(n)\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \Psi_n(t,s)$$ where $b(n)=2 n (n-1)$. Note you're formula is missing the $s^2$ preceding the second sum on the right-hand side and your value for $b(2)$ is also wrong.

@StevenClark Oh okay now I understand thanks. Do you see a way to  answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4910228/460999

I believe the coefficient in my previous comment should actually be $b(n)=n-1$. I posted an answer to your related question.

For
$$\Psi_n(t,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{n t}{s}} K_1\left(2 \sqrt{t n s}\right)\tag{1}$$
one has
$$t^2 \frac{\partial^3\, \Psi_n(t,s)}{\partial t^3}=n\, s^2 \frac{\partial\, \Psi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}\tag{2}$$
s0
$$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \Psi_n(t,s)\right)=s^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n\, \frac{\partial\, \Psi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}\\\qquad\qquad=s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Psi_n(t,s)\right)+s^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)\frac{\partial\, \Psi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}\tag{3}$$
so $b(n)=n-1$.

For $$\varphi_n(t,s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{n t}{s}} Y_1\left(2 \sqrt{t n s}\right)\tag{4}$$
one has
$$t^2 \frac{\partial^3 \varphi_n(t,s)}{\partial t^3}=-s^2 n \frac{\partial\, \varphi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}\tag{5}$$
so $$t^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \varphi_n(t,s)\right)=-s^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n\, \frac{\partial\, \varphi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}\\\qquad=-s^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \varphi_n(t,s)\right)-s^2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)\, \frac{\partial\, \varphi_n(t,s)}{\partial s}\tag{6}$$
so $r(n)=b(n)=n-1$.
